How do we distinguish between "not filled in" and "unknown" in our data store?
In our domain model "not filled in" and "unknown" are two different concepts. For example, time of death may be missing or, on the other hand, may be filled in as "unknown"
How do we honor that distinction in our data model (e.g. in Oracle DB)?
I figure we can reserve NULLs for "not filled". Then how do we describe "unknown"? Should we change the column type to some custom EXTENDED_DATE that has a special value for "unknown"? That would be a huge undertaking
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE date_type AS OBJECT (
    type VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE extended_date AS OBJECT (
    the_date DATE,
    type date_type
);


Given the assumption that there is only one 0 to 1 dates possible. I would recommend an additional attribute. @philip-kendall already has a suggestion I'd approve as well.
Is your domain model fixed? There might be multiple values possible.
You might have a test that came to a result and perform another test giving another result.
That way you could create a table for test results that either have a date (known date) or null (unknown date). You might have multiple test results or no test result (not filled).

Here be dragons! What today is "known," "unknown" and "not filled in" might change. Tomorrow it might be "sometime in 2019" where the month and day is unknown. Do all dates need to support known, unknown, and not specified? I would talk to your users more about what they need before deciding on a data structure. Previous questions indicate you are working on a medical application, which might provide additional constraints on the design.

When you store individual components, the distinction becomes clear. Then it becomes null, vs {} vs {year: 2024} vs {year:2024, month: 02} and so on, up to maximum detail. Storing the model and retrieving it exactly the same is an implementation detail.

@S.D. actually, Oracle DB has no notion of {}. NULL is the only special value

@S.D. But is {} distinct from {year: null}?

I was just reminiscing on another SE site that VB classic has "Empty", "Nothing" and "Null" to represent three different kinds of missing data each with different semantics. This problem has a long history.

Are all entries in this dataset confirmed dead or could there be alive entries?

@MonkeyZeus it's death certificates

In a more general situation (object-oriented programming), there is the "Special Case" design pattern.

I always prefer an explicit domain model - have an enum or similar KNOWN_DATE, UNKNOWN_DATE, NOT_FILLED and then a separate date column. The primary reason you might move away from this is for performance reasons, only you can determine if that's important for your use case or not.
Yes, it will be a lot of work. But there's no way round that, if it's important for your business then you need to do it.

Thank you! Do you suggest adding another column that stores those quasi-enum values describing what the date column value actually stands for? By the way, we typically have more than one date column in our tables

shrug - I don't know your domain model, your example was the one specific death date. My overall take is just that an implicit domain model (magic values etc) should be avoided, you can work out how best to handle that for your specific case.

@SergeyZolotarev If you're using an ORM like Entity Framework, value types allow for reusability here. You define one type with the two properties (enum + nullable datetime), use that everywhere, and EF will semi-automagically handle the two columns needed to store this data. If you're handcrafting your data structure and queries, well then you've inherently signed up for needing to handcraft it.

If you do use two separate columns, do not forget to add a constraint that checks (date_state = 'KNOWN_DATE') = (date_value IS NOT NULL)!

Situations may also arise where one may know something about a date, but not know it precisely.  One may know that it was between two dates, definitely was or wasn't on various days of the week, was sometime in the summer some years ago, but one doesn't remember how many, etc.  No single "date" field can, by itself, accommodate all such information.

What do you think of the custom type option?

This is basically what we are doing in our database design, although not with dates but with geographic coordinates which can have a varying degree of precision (e. g. "digitized" vs. "measured"). So if this information is important to your use case, this is the way to go.

@supercat when you go that deep down the rabbit hole you need a completely different system with infinite flexibility. Probably a separate table with "potential dates", each with a probability factor assigned, and an FK back to the main information table.

@supercat I had indeed a situation like that, where it's important we can enter both# "early 90s" or "30 April 1992". The problem is the expectation, if you need to do numerical operations like ordering them or graphing numbers/change over time.

I've seen various implementations that use the minimum represetable date as an unknown, I've also seen it with the maximum representable date when it was desired that the unknowns go to the end of the list.  You also see this with Unix time which starts at 1/1/70 and results in errant 1969 dates showing up when that's put into local time.  If you actually need inexact dates I would do it with a date range.

There's no simple "do it that way and you'll be fine" solution.
This is the approach that I would probably take:

Determine the actual use cases (entering and displaying data, storing into and retrieving from the database, searching and sorting). Apparently you've done a bit of that (you list "not filled in" and "unknown" as possible exceptional values which need to be entered and displayed), but there may be more, and it is not clear how these exceptions would affect search operations which is where mapping data into database concepts can get tricky.
Consider whether there are plausible future extensions that you don't need to implement now but which your design should not make too difficult to implement later. Depending on the domain, you may need to represent inexact or estimated dates (genealogy software has this a lot) or dates in different calendar systems (that might be interesting for historical events in different areas of the world). Don't overthink this but also don't ignore obvious plausible extensions.
Map into database concepts. As you already know, SQL databases typically have NULL as the only exceptional column value, so you will likely need more than one column to represent your dates. Using an enum which tells you whether your date is regular or one of a set of exceptional values would be pretty straightforward as long as you can satisfy your requirements with it, especially search and sort operations.

The result would likely look much like what @PhilipKendall wrote, unless there are more requirements which you don't detail here.

It is likely also wise to include CHECK constraints to ensure that the enum agrees with the date value (i.e. if the date is known, then it should not be NULL, and vice-versa).

One such additional "exceptional value" could be a date that's labeled "approximate". It's not truly unknown but still not exactly known.

It sounds like what you're essentially trying to do here is tease out the various different meanings of NULL and treat them systematically.
The problem is that there are not only a number of possible specific meanings of NULL in different contexts, but there also often remain ambiguous cases where it isn't possible to definitively categorise, or dual cases where the meaning depends on the processing being applied to the data (not on the intrinsic meaning of the data).
I use the example of a dog found injured on the street by a stranger and brought to a vet. From the vet's point of view, not only is the owner unknown, but whether the dog even has an owner is unknown (it could be a stray). If the dog has no owner, then the record of an owner is "inapplicable". If it has an owner who has not had chance to present themselves yet due to the circumstances, then the record is "missing". The problem is that these two cases are themselves ambiguous and unresolved - there is missing information about whether the owner information is missing or inapplicable. You then end up with a third "pending" case which could eventually collapse to one of the other two.
For records which withstand updates, there is also a possible distinction in some contexts between "missing-for-now" (action is being taken to seek the missing information) and "missing-permanently" (the missing condition is considered final).
You will often end up introducing a large amount of extra complexity to deal systematically with what are usually a spuriously small number of cases or relatively unimportant distinctions between unrecorded information.
If someone else has already determined a data model in which there are these distinctions and they make sense and are usable in context, then a solution to storing the different cases in SQL will often depend on desired performance and efficiency characteristics.
For example, simply storing a string value is the most flexible approach, since this can accommodate dates in string form plus any non-date special values. But if you need dates typed as dates when possible, you'll inevitably end up with at least a second field to hold an encoding of the special values which aren't part of SQL's date type.

A timestamp has two statuses: null and not null.
You are trying to infer three or more statuses from a datatype which can only communicate two.
What you can consider is another field which articulates the confidence of the timestamp or its absence.
Imagine a dataset more like this:
id  | time_of_death | time_of_death_confidence | translation (illustrative purposes only)
----|---------------|--------------------------|-----------------------------------------
0   | null          | unspecified              | is dead, time not specified, yet?
1   | null          | unknown                  | is dead, time forever unknown
2   | 20:34         | estimated                | is dead, estimated
3   | 10:55         | confirmed                | is dead, pinpointed
4   | 14:26         | null                     | this shouldn't happen...


This is a quite nice way to put it, I like it +1. Especially because it allows to talk about confidence in the null value as well. As in, "we're confident that the date is null", i.e. we know that the date is unknown.

@Al.G. Thanks! I'm cooking up a different way of wording OP's tribulation =)

On a first glance it may look that this is the same as Philip's answer, but there is an important difference: in your approach you do not have invalid states. For any date (weather null or not) you can have any confidence in it. Philip's answer though allows invalid states like (non-null date + "unknown" / "not filled" as enum state) which make no sense. (And by the way, I believe you should remove null from the confidence. How could you not know how confident you are otherwise haha)

But if you have N such columns, you're going to need 2N columns. That may be a lot

@SergeyZolotarev I don't understand your comment. I literally added just one column. No further columns are needed.

@MonkeyZeus that's only the case when only one column needs that kind of distinction. If there are, say, ten such columns. you're going to have as much additional "confidence" columns

@SergeyZolotarev Then make time_of_death a varchar field so that you can infer more than two statuses; this of course has monumental performance and convenience penalties. I'm really not sure what else to tell you. If you use my answer then you'll probably want to create a view with a bunch of decode() statements if you're looking to simplify application logic to achieve a specific text output.

I really don't understand why no-one suggests a custom type. Replacing an explicit type with a reference to a new table is another option (objects and tables are basically the same thing, a set of key-value pairs) but a bit of a kludge

@SergeyZolotarev Then why did you solicit answers? Go and follow through with your kludge. If you wanted to learn how to technically achieve your kludge then you should have asked that. My closing comment is don't let the whims of a business kludge your data model in costly ways.

One solution that I have seen for this in practice is to create a 'dates' reference table.  Your table will have a row for each actual date used as well as special dates.  This allows you to have 'unknown' (known to be unknown) and 'unspecified' (which aligns with your "not filled in").  This can also be used to support invalid dates which is useful if you have to record submitted data regardless of whether it is valid.
This complicates things a fair amount such as by introducing a lot of joins but it does allow for a fully correct data model in situations like this.
Per comments, here's a really simple (and probably naive) example of this kind of table:
key | date       | name             |
------------------------------------|
0   | null       | no value         |
1   | null       | unspecified      |
2   | null       | unknown          |
3   | 2024-10-15 | Oct 15, 2024     |
4   | 2024-10-16 | Oct 16, 2024     |

So instead of the actual date in your data table, you would have a FK constrained column pointing to the key of this table.
I want to be clear: this is not fun to work with and you shouldn't do this if you don't really need it.

"Your table will have a row for each actual date used as well as special dates." - how is that supposed to work? How are actual dates separated from special dates? What limits the number of special cases? What are the columns in this table? How would these rows be referenced? This design does appear to violate a number of normalisation rules.

@bergi My experience with this is using a structure defined by a vendor and I don't think I can divulge specifics, but I am told this is a 'by-the-book design' by people who know more about DBs than me.  Give me a minute and I will elaborate in the answer.

Thanks for adding the example, that's kinda what I imagined. But if this is by-the-book, it's a pretty bad book (or actually describing a different use case). The join really is the least issue. Problem 1: you can have multiple entities referencing the same date row (how to update?). Problem 2: you can have date rows not referenced by any entity (garbage collection anyone?). Problem 3: you can have an unrestricted number of "special" dates (anyone can add a new one). Problem 4: you can have disagreement between the date value and the name (like in row 4).

@Bergi This is fundamentally just a lookup table, isn't it? All those problems you list apply to lookup tables, and I'd be surprised if there is a consensus that lookup tables are considered bad

Nothing wrong with lookup tables in general, but they're just not suitable for the use case described by the OP.

Upvoted as fun thought experiment. This might generate even more hassle than creating a bespoke data type, which is slightly impressive.

@Bergi Problem 1 - This is not an issue.  The date in the date table is a date.  That date has a semantic meaning that is independed on the entities that are registered as died on that date.  The case where you want to say "2024-10-15" was actually "2024-10-16" is rather limited.  If you want to say John Doe did not die on "2024-10-15", rather he died on "2024-10-16" you change the reference on John Doe, potentially creating a new date.

@Taemyr Yes, making the rows in the table immutable solves the updating problem, but that semantic approach should have been specified in the answer. Could updating shared values actually be a use case? Yes, like fixing the name of the example row 4 to say "16th" instead of "15th". But then the two ways of updating would have to be distinguished (and explained to the user and made available in the UI), making the whole thing more complicated - probably unnecessary so. And if the rows really are immutable, there's no need to create a separate table, or at least not to add a surrogate key.

@Bergi: I believe this is precisely what the OP needs. In one of the comments, he says there are many date fields in this application, and possibly many date fields on the same table. Imagine a table with 5 date fields which can all be known, unknown, or not specified. You double the number of columns to support this data model. The model proposed in this answer centralizes this concept in a table, which allows for a single FK per date on other tables. (1/2)

(2/2) Now imagine you have these dates on many tables scattered all across the system. You double the number of "date" columns on all tables unless you create a table for this. It is no longer a "simple date." It becomes its own entity in the system, thus deserving its own table. The real problem is we have no date type which also embeds whether the date is known, unknown, or not specified.

@GregBurghardt "You double the number of columns to support this data model." - I would rather introduce a composite type or domain type for this, containing a date_value field and a date_type enum field, which could be used as a single column in any table. But that's Postgres, I don't know how Oracle does this (iirc they have object types as well?)

@Bergi "Problem 1: you can have multiple entities referencing the same date row (how to update?)." Yes, you definitely will have multiple entities pointed to the same values, unless somehow all your entities have different dates.  You would never update the values in this table under normal circumstances.  If your child tables need a different date, you point it to a different row.

@P.Hopkinson This isn't a thought experiment.  This is a real design that I have worked with for more than a decade.  It works, but yes, it is a bit of a hassle.

@Bergi "Thanks for adding the example, that's kinda what I imagined" I'm confused then that you say this violates normalization rows. Using extra columns to qualify a column is denormalized and this would be how you normalize that.  Which rules are you referring to?

@Bergi "Problem 3: you can have an unrestricted number of "special" dates (anyone can add a new one)." If 'anyone' can add a special date, your DB/system needs a security review.  But the ability to add unlimited number of special values is one of the benefits. Consider solving for 'NullFlavor'

@Bergi " Problem 2: you can have date rows not referenced by any entity (garbage collection anyone?)." You don't need to create a row unless it is used but, in the scheme of things, there aren't really a lot of dates. 100,000 rows would cover more than 2 centuries.

@JimmyJames Re Problem 1 and normalisation: I wasn't entirely sure how you imagined this to work. You want the rows to be immutable, and there probably should be a uniqueness constraint on name and a uniqueness constraint on date. That should be clarified in the answer imo. And what I don't like about this is that with those constraints, the name column could become the primary key and you don't need the surrogate key.

@JimmyJames Re Problem 3: it's not clear whether the OP needs that benefit, afaict they don't. What I don't like about this scheme is that "special dates" (which are decided on at design time, e.g. using that NullFlavor, or at best should be added/edited only by admins) are mixed with normal dates (that users - or the application - will need to add dynamically at run time) in the same table. A security policy capturing this would be a hassle. Or did you mean to pre-provision any date that might ever be needed?

@Bergi "A security policy capturing this would be a hassle." I don't know what you mean.  Are you accustomed to users having unfettered access to insert or modify data in a production database?  And any admin who makes unapproved data changes where I work would be disciplined if not fired.  The code required to check for a date and add it if necessary is trivial and if every date is expected to be used, you might as well pre-populate, yes.  In the more than a decade I have been working with this kind of table, none of the issues you mention have ever occurred.

@Bergi "the name column could become the primary key and you don't need the surrogate key" Sure you don't need it, but I don't know why you would want to use a char FK all over the place when a much smaller integer key can be used.  And it makes it easier to change the names.  The names aren't important for the actual dates and most of the time, you just want the date. The names are mainly used to distinguish between different non-date values.

@Bergi "I wasn't entirely sure how you imagined this to work" I'm not sure why people keep implying this is some idea I came up with.  It's a real thing that I work with.  And to be clear, when I first learned about it, I thought it was kind of silly. I think a union type or what you mention doing with Postgres is probably a much better solution. I don't think it's available in all major DBs, though.

@Bergi I asked what the book was and it's this: Data Warehouse Toolkit

@JimmyJames Re security policy, sure it's very simple to do this check in the application logic (or just not offer an API to modify the set of special dates). It's just that I prefer to lock my data model down at the database level already, so that no invalid data can ever be stored even by mistake.

@JimmyJames "I'm not sure why people keep implying this is some idea I came up with" - I'm not saying that, I believe you. You may want to emphasize or link the term "reference table" (also known as "domain table" or "lookup table"). However I haven't seen this concept applied to a mixture of two domains (special and normal dates), and I was confused by the apparently missing unique constraint on your example (before the edit).

@Bergi Sorry, yeah, I was rushing when I put the example up. I think we are done, thanks for the discussion.

You either know the date of birth or you don’t. You may know a partial birthday (someone was born in 1967, or their birthday is 6th of October). I may not have a birthdate for many reasons. Unknown (to the person themselves), never filled out, refused, a hospital might keep track of (yet) unborn babies, a statue has no birthdate, whatever i cannot think of.
You want one date field and one character field describing your information as soon as you have more than one kind of birthdates not in the database.
Don’t use out-of-band information. Many years ago people used 9-9-99 for non-existing birthdates, that thing is going to byte you with names, there is an actress named Rachel Null who was problems with databases all the time for obvious but stupid reasons.

I would challenge your domain model:

If the information is unknown, one can't fill it in.
If the information is not filled in, your system can't be sure if it is because the information is unknown or for another reason.

This implies that vases with "unknown" are in reality a subset of the cases "not filled in".  Storing them differently makes no sense, as they are not mutually exclusive.
You may object that in your case your system is able to make the difference. But how?

By deduction from another information? But then you already have what you need and there is no reason to create a redundant "unknown" information, that you would have to maintain in sync.
By allowing user to specify it? then you need to foreseen here another information from which your system can deduce if it's unknown. Go to first dash ;-)

P.S: Hardcore logicians would even claim that when an information is not filled in there is a probability that it is nevertheless known and another probability that it's unknown, and if both probabilities are derived
from different information sources, the total might not necessarily be 100%: welcome in the world of multivalued logic.

I think you might be missing the distinction between 'unknown' and 'unspecified'. 'Unknown' is a specified value which declares that the date is known to not be known. (Cue Donald 'Rummy' Rumsfeld.)

I agree with @JimmyJames. The OP has asked numerous questions revolving around a medical application. "Unknown" is good to know so every healthcare provider you meet doesn't ask you the same question when your answer is always "I don't know." Contrast that with "not specified" which could cue the healthcare worker to ask the question next time they see the patient. At which point the patient might give a date, or say "I don't know". Then the "not specified" becomes "Unknown" so they don't ask the patient again.

Of course, none of that is specified in the current question, which is why I voted to close as needing focus.

@JimmyJames On fact, I know pretty well the distinction between unknown and unspecified. My whole point is that this is quite theoretical and the system is not omniscient and cannot in practice make the difference between the two, unless there is an explicit information that tell it so.

"This implies that "unknown" is in reality a subset of "not filled in" and storing them differently makes no sense, as they are not mutually exclusive." This is what I am saying is wrong.  "specified to be unknown" is not a subset of unspecified.

@greg let's take a medical example. Patient arrives, there is a weight and blood pressure. In the system the nurse enters no weight: is it because she doesn't know (i.e. the patient could not be weighted because severely injured), or is it because the nurse could not enter the weight, for example, the patient was weighted but immediately fell conciousness requiring illediate attention. So I know thesre is a difference, but the system cannot know, unless there is a checkbox "the patient could not be weighted" or the sratz can be deduced from other info

@JimmyJames if you don't know you can't specify. So it is not as simple as that.  There are even multivalued logic which allow to state that it's more or less unknown and more or less unspecified.

I see what you mean by the system cannot distinguish between missing information, unknown information, or information that was purposefully not specified. That distinction is a human decision. The system need only provide the necessary values so the human can choose the appropriate one based on the circumstances, and then program logic and terminology in the UI to communicate the intent of those values. I think the difference between your idea and mine is precisely that: intent. (1/2)

(2/2) To be honest, I've had the same idea as described in your answer. Why do we need anything other than NULL? It isn't known. What difference does it make which kind of "unknown" it is? I think humans distinguish this sometimes, but it is highly dependent on the use case and the meaning of those different kinds of "unknown."

@GregBurghardt IIRC, Dr. Codd's (second) idea for relation models included 3 different 'nulls'.  I think they aligned with one for 'no value', one for 'value unknown' and the last was 'value unspecified'.

@Christophe "if you don't know you can't specify" But you can specify that you know you don't know. There's a difference between 'I know that X is unknown' and I don't know if X is known' and 'I know that X has no value'.

@JimmyJames, and Codd's 3 nulls were quickly considered 2 bridges too far!

To put it in a very simple way, suppose someone is digitising paper forms which have been filled in with pen or pencil. One of the fields in the form asks you to write a date which you may or may not know. If you do not know the date, you are supposed to write the word "unknown". It is quite possible and reasonable that whoever has to process these forms might want to do something different if the word "unknown" is written vs. if the field is left blank (e.g. if it's blank, maybe they could contact the person and check if they forgot to complete that part of the form).

@kaya3 I get it. But still, "unknown" is not a date. In a digitised version you would have a flag "unknown" next to the field. And this is exactly what I meant to say in my second  bullet at the end: the system cannot make the difference, unless you provide another information telling it explicitly it's unknown or letting it deduce that it's unknown. Then just store this extra information somewhere.

@Christophe Nobody said "unknown" is a date. The point is that the field is for either a date or the value "unknown", and the value can be missing, and the last two mean different things in the domain. There is nothing wrong with this domain model. In your answer you say: "You may object that in your case your system is able to make the difference. But how?", so, I explained the "how" with an example.

@Christophe If it helps, here's an example of a specification which requires this kind of model:

Also, there's a link in there to the deliciously named NullFlavor which is worth a look.

One option is to choose a specific date (e.g. 3000-01-01) which means "unknown".
This fulfils your brief but the use cases will be clumsy. Every time you use the field you will have to insert logic to say "but not those dates", in addition to any null handling.
Your code will be easier to read if you create additional field to hold this kind of special information, as suggested in the other answers.
